# Redirect in-IDE terminal for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal

I am using the [lanterna](http://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) library for Java to write a basic console based GUI. The library includes a Swing-based Terminal as well as the ability to output to the system's terminal application.

In IDEA, When I try to use the system terminal functionality with this library it outputs to the IDE terminal. Is there a way to make IntelliJ IDEA direct `stdout` to the system terminal instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have such feature. You can run the app in the real terminal and use Remote debugging instead.